# Managing or Reducing noise in a mosaic raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, mosaic, nodata, noise

I have created a raster with the *Mosaic to New Raster* tool from 3 separate rasters. However in my mosaic I have some consecutive pixels which seem to be the noise of the previous procedure. Is there any tool or something as to isolate them transforming them to No Data?

I have no idea how much overlapping was and I think the method I used was the default "Last".

[image: image-noise]

Comment: That appears to be a DEM raster, is that correct? Would it be possible to provide a link to your original three rasters or their source? It's a bit of an odd pattern, but I suspect the problem is caused by the raster overlap and how the overlapping values were combined. That or if you're referring to something other than the mosaicking when you say 'previous procedure' it would be helpful to know what that was.

Comment: Yes it's a dem raster.unfortunately a link isn't possible.  Previous procedure i mean the use of mosaic to new raster tool. Any suggestion for overlapping? Is it better if i use another method (mean, last, first, etc.)? or is there any way that i can calculate the noise or something else?

Comment: Well if you're using last it means those pixels are coming from one of the three inputs and you should take a look at that particular one to see what's going on along that edge. If there's sufficient overlap you can just null out that area (or crop it or change the stack order in mosaicking) and it will take the values from a different raster. A different method might lessen the impact (say, mean), but it would still show up since there's such a marked difference. There are some smoothing tools/methods in Spatial Analyst if you have it, but I'm not versed enough to know the best one or method.

Comment: @ChrisW thank you, for your response. I ve tried several methods but the noise still remains

Comment: Unfortunately without access to the original source files I can't offer much more. I've added the DEM tag which might attract the attention of some other potential answerers.